# Excel Text-to-Columns changing date format

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm having an issue with Excel VBA and the Text-to_Columns.

I have 30+ text files, some containing dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY. I'm using a VBA macro to import them, remove data that is not needed, and then recombining the files into a CSV format. The smallest files contain about 600 rows and 20 columns, the largest contain 1,000,000 rows and 93 columns (800mb+ file).

When I extract them using VBA text to columns codes, the formats of the dates changes from DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY. (e.g. 05/11/2015 - 5th November, 2015 becomes 11/05/2015, 11th May, 2015). The dates are not normally in the same column, and never have the same name in each file.

This is the VBA code used:

```
  Sub Stripper()
' Go through each spreadsheet, and extract from Text-to-column
' System allows for 150 columns
' Text-to-column can handle commas, semicolons, and pipe delimitations

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

   Dim y As Variant
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim MT As Integer
    Dim Cd As Integer

    k = Sheets.Count

y = 1
MT = 0
Cd = 0

    While y <= k
        t = Sheets(y).Name

        If t = "Launch" Then

        ElseIf Left(t, 4) = "MFGI" Or IsNumeric(Left(t, 1)) = True Then

            Worksheets(t).Activate

            Columns("A:A").Select
            Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
            :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), _
                Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), _
                Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), _
                Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), _
                Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(38, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(40, 1), _
                Array(41, 1), Array(42, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(44, 1), Array(45, 1), Array(46, 1), Array(47, 1), Array(48, 1), Array(49, 1), Array(50, 1), _
                Array(51, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(53, 1), Array(54, 1), Array(55, 1), Array(56, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(59, 1), Array(60, 1), _
                Array(61, 1), Array(62, 1), Array(63, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(65, 1), Array(66, 1), Array(67, 1), Array(68, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(70, 1), _
                Array(71, 1), Array(72, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(74, 1), Array(75, 1), Array(76, 1), Array(77, 1), Array(78, 1), Array(79, 1), Array(80, 1), _
                Array(81, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(83, 1), Array(84, 1), Array(85, 1), Array(86, 1), Array(87, 1), Array(88, 1), Array(89, 1), Array(90, 1), _
                Array(91, 1), Array(92, 1), Array(93, 1), Array(94, 1), Array(95, 1), Array(96, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(99, 1), Array(100, 1), _
                Array(101, 1), Array(102, 1), Array(103, 1), Array(104, 1), Array(105, 1), Array(106, 1), Array(107, 1), Array(108, 1), Array(109, 1), Array(110, 1), _
   Array(111, 1), Array(112, 1), Array(113, 1), Array(114, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(116, 1), Array(117, 1), Array(118, 1), Array(119, 1), Array(120, 1), _
            Array(121, 1), Array(122, 1), Array(123, 1), Array(124, 1), Array(125, 1), Array(126, 1), Array(127, 1), Array(128, 1), Array(129, 1), Array(130, 1), _
            Array(131, 1), Array(132, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(134, 1), Array(135, 1), Array(136, 1), Array(137, 1), Array(138, 1), Array(139, 1), Array(140, 1), _
            Array(141, 1), Array(142, 1), Array(143, 1), Array(144, 1), Array(145, 1), Array(146, 1), Array(147, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(149, 1), Array(150, 1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        s = 1
        lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        While s <= lastColumn
            Cells(1, s).EntireColumn.Select
            If Cells(1, s) = "Original Data Source" Or Cells(1, s) = "Original Data Source Table/Field" Then
                Selection.Delete
                lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Else
                s = s + 1
            End If

        Wend

        Range(Cells(1, s), Cells(1, s + 30)).EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.Delete

        MT = MT + 1

    End If

    y = y + 1

Wend

Worksheets("Launch").Activate
Range("D28") = y - 2
Range("F28") = MT
    Range("D31") = Cd

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

Is there any way to stop VBA changing the dates around as it is throwing out all the reconciliation on the files?

Comment: I had the same problem with the dates, and if I remember correctly I was able to fix with a CDate() around the values, but I'm not sure how that can be applied to your code, if the dates aren't in the same columns.

Comment: The problem is that to fix it in `TextToColumns`, you need to supplpy the correct date format as the second value in the relevant array within the `FieldInfo` parameter. If you don't know which column that is, it will be tricky. Since you know it will convert them to US format if it can, you'll have to search afterwards for date values and reverse month/day and also find date strings and convert using `CDate` as @Alex4336 said.

Comment: It sounds as if you have already collated these ~30 TXT/CSV files into a single workbook with each worksheet containing one of the files. None of the files have been split; instead residing in column A with the header in A1. You need some interpretive process that will loop through the worksheets and determine the [XlColumnDataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241018%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for each destination column (sometimes over 100 fields). Does that sound about right?

Comment: @Jeeped that sounds about right. How do I use XlColumnDataType with what I already have?

Comment: I had dug up an old freebie add-in that I had been working on. It preprocesses the first 64 lines looking to identify common problems like MDY vs. DMY, part numbers greater than 15 digits or with leading zeroes like DUNS numbers that have to be retained, that sort of thing. This is similar to the 'look-ahead' that an SQL server does or the Schema.ini that identifies import field types for Access. It takes the info and builds an array of arrays of field types to be used in the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://goo.gl/ZAhTxa). I could go back to it but don't expect anything for a day or so.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is quite simple although it took me a while to find the answer. in "Array(6, 1)" the last "1" is the format of the cell. 1 means general, that is Excel tries to determine what the cell contains, text, date, numbers. If you are sure the cell contains a date, change that value to 4 in order to format the cell as date DD/MM/YY. Array(6, 4).
See this article from Microsoft for all the values: [XlColumnDataType Enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype)
This is a lick to the complete article [Range.TextToColumns Method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns)
I hope this helps you guys along